# wxpython's SetTransparent doesn't capture user input if set to an opacity of zero

Tags: python, wxpython, opacity, transparent, invisible

I'm trying to make a wxpython window (only a window in the sense that it's a window object).. that fills the entire screen and is completely invisible. I then want to allow the user to click and drag within the "window" (ie. anywhere on the screen).

When I try doing `self.SetTransparent(0)` user input doesn't get captured by the window.

Is this intended behaviour?

Is this the correct way to achieve what I want? An opacity of `1` is obviously indistinguishable to the human eye, but I'm still curious as to why I can't make it completely transparent.

Here's the snippet:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        style = (wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.NO_BORDER)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Invisible", style=style)

        self.SetTransparent(0) # This doesn't work
        #self.SetTransparent(1) # But this works fine

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyPress)

    def OnKeyPress(self, event):
        """quit if user press q or Esc"""
        if event.GetKeyCode() == 27 or event.GetKeyCode() == ord('Q'): #27 is Esc
            self.Close(force=True)
        else:
            event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
frm = Frame()
frm.ShowFullScreen(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Or is there a way of giving the window no background at all rather than a completely transparent coloured background?

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with answering your question, but what use do you have for such code?  The only thing I can think of is either a key-logger or bad design.

Comment: A screenshot tool that allows you to select a section of the screen to be cropped, and then uploaded. See [gyazo](http://gyazo.com/).

Comment: You're right though, thinking about it I'll probably have a transparent layer over the screen to make it obvious that the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND` to accomplish the same effect.

I also cleaned up other aspects of the code.

Behaves slightly differently on XP versus 7, but probably not an issue for the type of app you're describing.

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(None)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)
    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        pass # do nothing
    def OnLeftDown(self, event):
        print event.GetPosition()
    def OnKeyDown(self, event):
        if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            self.Close()
        else:
            event.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.ShowFullScreen(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```